# mkmapview thumbnail image

Tags: iphone, ios4, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am  creating  thumbnail image in MKMAPView without Google logo ,Is it Acceptable by Apple?
like below Example Thumbnail

```
  CGPoint annotationPoint = [mapView convertCoordinate:view.annotation.
    coordinate toPointToView:_mapView];

 float boxDY=annotationPoint.y;
float boxDX=annotationPoint.x;
CGRect box = CGRectMake(boxDX,boxDY,100,100);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_mapView.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect
  ([image  CGImage],CGRectMake(box.origin.x-30, box.origin.y-35,75, 75))];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's Acceptable without 'Google logo', because main map view have 'Google logo'